# Parse array coming into Zapier

Tags: json, zapier

I'm fairly new to Zapier and at present I am using the Zapier webhooks to retrieve information that comes from one of my vendors. The problem is some of the values that need to extract from the vendor are not coming in as a single string but rather as some type of array. I was wondering if anyone here had an idea on how i would go about splitting up the information i receive here so i can map them to the correct fields in my CRM.

Here is what the value looks like when i first view it in Zapier:

```
active: True id: 138371 memo: AcmeCo modifiedOn: 2017-03-17T19:01:30.0774473 type: Email value: name@acmeco.com active: True id: 138370 memo: None modifiedOn 2017-03-17T19:01:30.0764491 type: MobilePhone value: 7652456789
```

I would like to be able to get the following values and map them:
Email
memo
MobilePhone

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the webhook data coming from your vendor's app is not in the correct format. Some common formats include form-encoded, JSON, and XML. Zapier will interpret the format and break apart the individual fields/values so you can easily map them. [Some more information here](https://zapier.com/blog/how-use-zapier-webhooks/).

Answer (score 0):

While it is not in the "correct" format, i was able to extract the information I needed by using the Zapier Formatter > Text and using the following syntax:

```
MobilePhone[:newline:]value:
```

and selecting `Second` in the segment index.

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone.